# Change URL using wordpress redirecting domain

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, redirect, cpanel

I have my own domain

`www.mxm.com` (just an example)

and i create other page with this url:

```
www.mxm.com/testpage1
```

in the carpet testpage1 i installed wordpress and i redirect to

`www.testpage1.com` in my cpanel.

So now i can enter `www.testpage1.com` with no problem but when i click in other menu item like blog the url change to:

```
www.mxm.com/testpage1/blog
```

I want to know how to change

`www.mxm.com/textpage1/blog`

I want to get

```
www.testpage1.com/blog
```

I was reading something about editing wp-config.php or wp-setting.php but i didn't get it.

There is a way? I'm kind of newbie using wordpress. Thanks btw.

Comment: Have you checked your database, so in wp_options make sure the urls are reflecting your website

Comment: I just edit the home url and it works! with the link but now it don't enter in the other pages. How i can redirect the pages from www.mxm.com/textpage1/menu-items ?

Comment: Can you show me provide me a temp login? I can help you further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it!
I just edit the .htaccess and the table with credentials on my DB and it works.
Other way i found was changing it with the dashboard of Wordpress. In settings there is a field where u can change the address of wordpress and for the website.

This two urls help me a lot:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/problem-moving-wp-now-only-the-home-page-works
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/redirect-a-domain-to-my-wordpress-url